# understand how reshape function forms matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

let us consider following matrix  for illustration

```
A=rand(6,3)

A =

    0.3500    0.8308    0.7537
    0.1966    0.5853    0.3804
    0.2511    0.5497    0.5678
    0.6160    0.9172    0.0759
    0.4733    0.2858    0.0540
    0.3517    0.7572    0.5308
```

to total we have 6*3=18 element,after apply reshape function

```
reshape(A,2,9)

ans =

0.3500    0.2511    0.4733    0.8308    0.5497    0.2858    0.7537    0.5678    0.0540
0.1966    0.6160    0.3517    0.5853    0.9172    0.7572    0.3804    0.0759    0.5308
```

clearly if we look on original array,then we can easily see that rows of these new matrix is same as

```
B=A(:)'

B =

  Columns 1 through 9

    0.3500    0.1966    0.2511    0.6160    0.4733    0.3517    0.8308    0.5853    0.5497

  Columns 10 through 18

    0.9172    0.2858    0.7572    0.7537    0.3804    0.5678    0.0759    0.0540    0.5308

>> B(1:2:18)

ans =

    0.3500    0.2511    0.4733    0.8308    0.5497    0.2858    0.7537    0.5678    0.0540
```

so in reshape(A,m,n) where m*n must be total element,m represent starting form first element in first column,increment  in columns until nth element?also when i have tried

```
reshape(A,3,4)
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

it gives me error,so whenever i choose n,m must be  number of elements in array divided by n right?thanks in advance

Comment: yes, `n*m` must equal `numel(A)`. But you can do this also: `reshape(A,3,[])` and let `reshape` automatically choose the size of the dimension you use `[]` for.

Comment: what exactly is your question ?

Comment: the same can be done with reshape(A,[],3) right

Comment: role of  m and n in reshape(A,m,n) and how they are working

Comment: it is not worth to downvote,but for me important is just knowledge

Comment: @datodatuashvili m,n represent the columns and rows. Of course you may change the order of m,n thus instead of converting it to `2x9`matrix (your example) you would convert it to `9x2`. As you said the number of elements (n*m) must be exactly the same. If you want to change that by adding NaN values. You would have to reshape it into 1D, add the NaNs you need and reshape it to the wanted form.

Comment: two downvote does not  decrease my knowledge,thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab stores its matrices column-wise. This means internally it basically is just one array where all the columns are concatenated. The shape of the matrix is stored seperately.

I don't quite understand your last question, because your matrix A has 18 entries, but you try to reshape it into a matrix with 3*4=12 entries

I hope this helped you

Comment: that was my another question,if m*n must be equal to total element

Answer (score 1):

`Reshape` is for **reordering** elements as explained in [@alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24138493/684399) *(and of course the number of elements must not change!)*. If you want to **resize** a matrix, use [indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

#### Examples

```
A = rand(6,6) % Start matrix

A =

    0.0113    0.5362    0.3510    0.7220    0.2084    0.8344
    0.5013    0.9770    0.5221    0.5743    0.8442    0.8102
    0.1214    0.0390    0.9594    0.1385    0.9038    0.6081
    0.2480    0.9165    0.1986    0.3692    0.5135    0.6154
    0.3631    0.9843    0.3697    0.5964    0.6437    0.6901
    0.9978    0.8182    0.1990    0.8273    0.6811    0.2464
```

#### Use '[]' to remove lines or columns

```
A(2:3, :) = [] % This removes 2nd and 3rd lines
A(:, [2 5]) = [] % This further removes 2nd and 5th columns

A =

    0.0113    0.3510    0.7220    0.8344
    0.2480    0.1986    0.3692    0.6154
    0.3631    0.3697    0.5964    0.6901
    0.9978    0.1990    0.8273    0.2464
```

#### Use indexing for zero padding

```
AA = zeros(6, 6); % Build larger matrix the size you want ...
AA([1 2 4 6], [2 3 5 6]) = A % Place elements of `A` inside `AA` as you wish ...
```

AA =

```
     0.0000   0.0113   0.3510   0.0000   0.7220   0.8344
     0.0000   0.2480   0.1986   0.0000   0.3692   0.6154
     0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
     0.0000   0.3631   0.3697   0.0000   0.5964   0.6901
     0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
     0.0000   0.9978   0.1990   0.0000   0.8273   0.2464
```

#### With indexing you can also play around to create bigger/smaller matrices.

```
A([4 4 1 1 2 3], end:-1:1)

ans =

    0.2464    0.8273    0.1990    0.9978
    0.2464    0.8273    0.1990    0.9978
    0.8344    0.7220    0.3510    0.0113
    0.8344    0.7220    0.3510    0.0113
    0.6154    0.3692    0.1986    0.2480
    0.6901    0.5964    0.3697    0.3631
```